# (Android) How to detect and get colorPrimaryDark color of launch app

Tags: android, colors, status

For example, if i run "Google play" app then status bar (colorPrimaryDark) have a green color, if i run "You tube" app then status bar (colorPrimaryDark) have a red color.
How to detect and get this color?
if you know, please tell me a solution.
Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

change `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">XXXX</color>` in color.xml file which XXXX is the color code you like

Comment: No. I want to get color of launch app. for example, when i start "Google play" app, i will get color of GPlay is green color. when i start "Youtube" app, i will get color of Youtube if red color. you understand?